# How to get values from hasMany relations with PIVOT table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections

I have the following tables:

**users**

- id
- name

**cattle_types**

- id
- user_id
- name

**properties**

- id
- user_id
- name

**properties_cattle_types**

- id
- cattle_type_id
- property_id
- quantity

I get all cattle types related to user through hasMany relation defined in user model:
`Auth::user()->cattleTypes`

But I need also take SUM of 'quantity' all notes that defined in pivot table **properties_cattle_types**.
I don't know how to take it all in one query, in order to near every cattle columns was column "quantity".
For example now in the result one note I have:

```sql
"id" => 1
"user_id" => 1
"name" => "Branders"
```

But I want

```sql
"id" => 1
"user_id" => 1
"name" => "Branders"
"quantity" => "560"
```

Or approximately so.

I've managed get almost what I need by following way:

```php
$cattleTypesForCurrentUser = Auth::user()->cattleTypes;
$totalCattleTypesForCurrentUser = [];

foreach ($cattleTypesForCurrentUser as $cattleTypeForCurrentUser) {
    $totalCattleTypesForCurrentUser[] = 
        DB::select('SELECT ( SELECT `name` FROM cattle_types WHERE id = ? )
            as `name`,
            ( SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM properties_cattle_types WHERE cattle_type_id IN (?) ) 
            as `quantity`',
        [$cattleTypeForCurrentUser->id, $cattleTypeForCurrentUser->id]
    );
}
dd($totalCattleTypesForCurrentUser);
```

But I suggest this way is terrible. I'm doing too many query in database inside **foreach**.
How can I do it by a good and correct way ??? Please help coworkers!(

Comment: Only laravel calls junction tables as pivot tables, so the pivot table tag refers to something completely different than what you are asking about.

Comment: @Shadow in CattleTypes model I have this relation: 
public function properties()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'properties_cattle_types')
            ->withPivot('id', 'quantity');
    }
But I cant access to it using Auth::user()->cattleTypes->properties.
I need somehow get sum of quantity every cattle_type from pivot table to show total quantity in blade

Comment: Given your database design it is entirely possible that `properties_cattle_types` ends up relating properties from one user with cattle_types from another user. This sounds like not what you intended to do. You might want to review your design to prevent this from happening. I'm going to go ahead and assume that cattle_types might be more appropriately associated with properties

Answer (score 0):

I would normalize your tables even further. As things stand, if you have two users, each of whom have (I dunno) Guernsey cows, then you would have multiple entries in your cattle types table for the same type of cattle.

Instead, you would be better with the following tables :

**users**

- id
- name

**cattle_types**

- id
- name

**users_cattle_types**

- id
- user_id // Foreign key to id on **users**
- cattle_type_id // Foreign key to id on **cattle_types**
- quantity // Example

The principle for the properties side of things would be the same.

Then in your User model you would use a hasManyThrough relationship to associate your user to their cattle types.